# Bash - pipe multiple grep and print output

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I am writing a shell script which will grep a document for certain words and then displaying the found words in colour output.

```
echo $(egrep -wi --color=always 'error|exception' $logFile)
```

now I want to combine this grep with another one to exclude a few results
For this I want to pipe above command to a grep command to exclude certain patterns

```
grep -vi '<status>error</status>'
```

For some reason this fails when I try to execute the command

```
echo $(egrep -wi --color=always 'error|exception' $logFile | $(grep -v '<STATUS>ERROR</STATUS>') )
```

or even if I try

```
echo $(egrep -wi --color=always 'error|exception' $logFile | grep -v '<STATUS>ERROR</STATUS>')
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is this failing?

Comment: output=$(egrep -wi --color=always 'error|exception' $logFile | grep -v '<STATUS>ERROR</STATUS>') echo $output

Comment: `echo $(foo)` is essentially the same as `foo` by itself.

Comment: It is not working==> line 87: ERROR: command not found

Comment: Post your line 87. Execute script with flag "-x" and post line 87.

Comment: Line 87 is the above mentioned command : echo $(egrep -wi --color=always 'error|exception' $logFile | $(grep -v '<STATUS>ERROR</STATUS>') )

Comment: Please explain  in the question what exactly happens. Vague terms like "fails" and "failing" are not helpful.

Comment: in return some hints: 1) http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/commandsub.html 2) `grep` expects a pattern, not a literal string 3) test commans in isolation

Comment: A regular expression doesn't have to contain metacharacters like `*` or `.`; such a string simply matches only itself. It makes sense to use them with `grep`, which can match substrings in the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems append only with egrep, --color=always, and -i.

```
egrep -wi --color=always 'error|exception' /tmp/log.log | grep -v '<STATUS>ERROR</STATUS>'
```

doesn't work but

```
egrep -w --color=always 'error|exception' /tmp/log.log | grep -v '<STATUS>ERROR</STATUS>'
```

and

```
egrep -wi --color 'error|exception' /tmp/log.log | grep -v '<STATUS>ERROR</STATUS>'
```

and

```
grep -wi --color=always 'error|exception' /tmp/log.log | grep -v '<STATUS>ERROR</STATUS>'
```

does...
But I don't know why your solution does'nt work...

In shell script:

```
result=`grep -wi --color=always 'error|exception' /tmp/log.log | grep -v '<STATUS>ERROR</STATUS>'`
echo $result
```

Comment: the command works fine on cmd line, but inside the shell script it fails.
That is what my main query is, how can I output the result of piped grep from the shell script